# How i can post from input values to Database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql

I want to send post request from the input here to the database, im beginner and trying to manage to do that, can someone help me here please what i have to do in order to achieve my goal ?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Task from "./Task";
import "./App.scss";

function App() {
  //Value of Input
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);

  const addTodos = async (e) => {
    if (val == "") return;
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/message")
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    /** */
    setTodos([...todos, val]);
    setVal("");
    /** */
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/message");
      setMessage(res.data);
    };
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((_, key) => key !== id));
  }; //#endregion

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/** On change values*/}
      <form onSubmit={addTodos}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
          value={val}
          type="text"
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo, key) => (
          <Task todo={todo} key={key} myKey={key} handleDelete={handleDelete} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      {message.map((e) => (
        <div>{e.todo}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//server js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const { Client } = require("pg");
const client = new Client({
  user: "jj",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "dbname",
  password: "rootuser",
  port: 5432,
});
client.connect();
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/message", async (req, res) => {
  const { rows } = await client.query(`SELECT * from todo`);
  res.send(rows);
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port 5174.`);
});
```

Should i also create a path in node js for the same server for the post request, then do the same in react using useEffect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to add a new route in your `server.js` file like this:

```
app.get("/message", async (req, res) => {
   const { rows } = await client.query(`SELECT * from todo`);
   res.send(rows);
});

app.post("/message", async (req, res) => {
   // run some logic in the database
});
```

This will make it so in the frontend, when you call a `GET` request to `/message`, then it will run the `app.get("/message")` code, but when you call a `POST` request to `/message`, it will will run the `app.post` code.

Hope this helps.

P.S. You may need to run some middleware to parse the data on the POST request. Essentially what is the idea with POST requests is that the client will send some data, like JSON, to the body of the request, and then you will use middleware to parse the request's body into editable JS objects that will be used to do something with the database.